# how to download ruby onto chromebook for TOP

Tags: ruby, installation, google-chrome-devtools, chromebook

am beginning my coding and programming journey so i am not entirely knowledgeable so bear with me.

i was reccomended the odin project for a better learning framework against the code camps i was in; and when i went to download Ruby (am on the fullstack path) on my chromebook it gives either mac os or linux as [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQY3I.png) i was told i could just use linux but that wasnt the [case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Ifa.png), does anybody know what to do? or if i need a specific program to be able to use TOP and ruby? - this is what i get for choosing a chromebook over a dell tbh.

i tried reaching out to people in TOP discord who have been using TOP for a while but not a lot of people use chromebooks for coding.
i tried following the instructions as it said for linux as that was my best option but to no avail.
i tried googling but it led me here and i am hopeful that someone may know where to start.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-2fEOeRG8A

Comment: Once you install Linux consider using [Jupyter Notebook](https://www.codecademy.com/article/jupyter-notebook-chromebook). Jupyter Notebook is best known for running Python code but for some time it's also supported Ruby and other languages.

Comment: This is where [Cloud VSCode](https://vscode.dev) comes in handy.

Comment: Newer versions of ChromeOS support Android apps. Assuming you aren't replacing the OS, if you can't find a native Android or Chrome extension for Ruby consider an online IDE like Replit or AWS Cloud9, or SSH into a VPS for development.